# Should the ssl and the ssl-certificate tag be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are questions in [ssl](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl) and [ssl-certificate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl-certificate). Should they be merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a look at the first page of SSL questions and they aren't always about certificates. While they are related, they aren't the same so I think no.